# Running JAR files in Windows 10

Tags: java, windows, weblogic

I have the **same domain user with Administrator privileges** in a Windows 7 environment and in a Windows 10 environment.

```
java -jar c:\fmw_12.2.1.0.0_wls_quick.jar ORACLE_HOME=C:\weblogic
```

When I run the above command, in Win 10 gives following error(but not in Win 7).

> Unable to access or modify the system registry.  Select Run as Administrator when opening the Command Prompt and try again.

Running as Admin works in Win 10. But is there any way to execute this command in Win 10 without explicitly running as Admin even when logged in user is also a Admin?

Comment: You can disable UAC. I wouldn't recommend it, but perhaps you already did in Win 7, so...

Comment: This probably goes better on SuperUser as this is Windows-related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply a problem with the UAC level in windows, not specific to win 10.

I could use [batch script from this link](https://sites.google.com/site/eneerge/scripts/batchgotadmin) to prompt for the Admin privileges when executing the jar.